# React Native tabBarItemStyle width not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have been working on a Bottom Tab Navigator and try to make tab bar items being highlighted with a circle shape around the icon when they are selected. I tried to set the height and width inside tabBarItemStyle, however, only height changes while width does not change. Is there something else I missed? How can I set the width so that the highlighted part is in a circle shape?
Here is a demo of the tab bar I am working on.
https://snack.expo.dev/qLi7s9qAA

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because the width value is being overridden by the containers flexbox property.

A quick easy fix is to use the maxWidth property instead of width in tabBarItemStyle properties.

There's a nice article here: https://mastery.games/post/the-difference-between-width-and-flex-basis/ that explains it.

Comment: I did tried to use maxWidth, but the tab items would then shifts to left side. How can I re-center them in this situation?